# How do I get the size of a gif with ImageMagick?

Tags: image, vb6, imagemagick

I am using the following code through vb6 using ImageMagick for the information of the images loaded via system

```
objectImage.identify ("- format", "% b", myImage)
```

AMs when I carry a gif it gives me several times the size 72727272, I believe that 72 is the frame size

I would like to know how to pull the total size of ums gif

Comment: What do you mean by 'ums gif'? Do you want to get total file size, if so why not use FileLen function instead of IM?

Comment: I suspect you need to remove the space between `-` and `format`, and also the space between `%` and `b`.

Comment: Sorry, but when I posted on stackflow ended up with space, but in my code do not have space ....

Yes, I would like to get the entire file, I am using IM because I have to deal with images